# manage event on parent>child hover css

Tags: css, css-selectors, parent-child, siblings

I have this html code

```
<article>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="a_b"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="c"></div>
</article>
```

I need to do some changes to div .c on div .a_b hover
Can I do this using scss (or native css), without using any javascript code?

Comment: I'm not sure, what are you trying to make? Tooltips, dropdown data?
As far as I know you'll have to use javascript or jQuery.

Comment: I need to show div .c when hover on div .a_b

Comment: No its not possible by just using CSS. There is no link between div.c and div.a_b, scss or any kind of CSS framework get converted to CSS only.

Comment: No, you will have to use javascript or jQuery

Comment: You can use  `~` to style siblings, but not parents. See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/aa0zykpe/ -

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: No, i've already tried this solution but it doesn't work. Thanks anyway. I think I'll do it using js..

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the `:hover` pseudo-class (and other pseudo-classes like `:focus`, `:checked`, `:target` etc.) to modify the styles on:

- the element itself
- a descendant of that element
- a subsequent sibling of the element.

In this setup:

```
<article>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="a_b"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="c"></div>
</article>
```

You can apply a pseudo-element to `.a` and it could modify the styles on `.a` (itself), `.a_b` (its child) or `.c` (its sibling).

But a pseudo-element on either `.a_b` or `.c` can't modify the styles on any element except the element itself - because neither element has any children or any subsequent siblings.

---

**The solution:**

In your structure, add `.a_b` as a subsequent sibling of `.a`:

```
<article>
    <div class="a">
    </div>
    <div class="a_b"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
</article>
```

and then use CSS positioning to re-position `.a_b` so that visually, it appears to be inside `.a` (even though it is actually a sibling element of `.a`, rather than a child element of `.a`).

Comment: Thanks, but I need .a_b to be inside .a div. So I did it using js

Comment: No worries. You can always say "Thanks" with an upvote rather than just writing "Thanks" in the comments. ;-) Appreciated. Happy Christmas!